# Find intersection of two lines having two points for each one (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, coordinates, line, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection's coordinates which are created from two lines using Matlab. Each line can be created through two known points. My main difficulty is that I don't know **how I can exceed the line's limits outside the two points**.

The data are, a set of points and XY axis.
[image]

And I need the (X,Y) coordinates.
[image]

Thank u in advanced.

Comment: That answer is not the same as the pair of points is line's endpoints. On my issue I have to exceed lines limits in order to find intersection's coordinates!

Comment: The linked accepted answer does work for your case. Try it with this test data: `x = [1 3; 2 4]; y = [0 1; 1 0];` You'll see that the solution `xi = 2.5; yi = 1.5;` lies *outside* both line segments. You don't have to extend them.

Comment: According author's code x=[1 3; 2 4] are the starting points and y = [0 1; 1 0] are the ending points.That means that the first line is created between (1,3) and (0,1) and similar the second one. So,if I m not wrong the intersection point should be somewhere at x1=2-3 (aprox) and y1= 5-6 (aprox) ,so the code does not work.

Comment: I'm actually the author. `x` is a matrix that contains the starting x coordinates in the first row and ending x coordinates in the second row (i.e. each column contains the x coordinates for one line). The same goes for `y`. So the first line goes from `(1,0)` to `(2,1)` and the second line goes from `(3,1)` to `(4,0)`.

Comment: You re absolutely right. Thank you for your time!